# what is the best way to change column type in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have column `balance` with data type `double`, but I want to change it for storing price in proper way. I want to make it `decimal`.

For that I am trying I am doing following

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('billing', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
        $table->decimal('balance', 8, 2)->change();
    });
}
```

But I am confused about down function, should I revert it back, I mean the previous data type?

Can someone kindly guide me about that, I will be thank full. Thank you

Comment: Column type changes are often non-revertible. You could just change the column back and accept data loss though. The point is to get the database in a state that an older version of your code can work with.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to define a drop function for an up function which alters a column.

Because `drop()` is intended to delete a table and maybe cascade the action. 
And your initial `billing` migration file should already have a drop definition for deleting that table.

So you can safely keep the `down()` function empty in your new migration file

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the reason why I am confuse, You can see @svikramjeet's answer which is explaining something else.

Comment: @ImranAbbas If you define a down function reverting the column back to a data type ( which I assume would not be a logical use case), you will forget why you did it in the long run. So keep it simple, define down for new table definitions for alterations which you keep choose to skip them

Comment: @SapneshNaik: This is purpose of down function in laravel to revert to previous state.If forgetting the use case cannot be the  reason for not using down function.

Comment: The only case where we need to keep down function blank is where we are updating column to nullable.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of down method is to revert the change to  state which was exactly same before running the up method of migration.If you are changing any user type in up() then it should be reverse in down() ideally.So your migration will end like this:

```
   public function up()
    {
      //double to decimal
    }

  public function down()
    {
     //decimal to double
    }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this is the reason why I am confuse, You can see @SapneshNaik's answer which is explaining something else.

Answer (score 1):

`down()` is used when you rollback the migrations. Let's assume you already migrated new changes to your database and you wrote nothing for `down()`. In this case, no matter you rollback you will have that new changed column with `decimal`. If you write code that reverts `decimal` into `double` again, You will get no harm when you rollback. It will stay as it was before you migrate.

Comment: In your case revert it back

Comment: Yes agreed @SomeDev :+1

Answer (score 0):

I usually think it this way.

If this migration prevents previous migration to be able to rollback, I need to revert using `down()`.

For example, If I created a new constraint between two existing table, which could not successfully dropped if I didn't revert the constraint creation. I would need to revert it.

In your case, changing type of a column will not affect the rollback in someway. So you don't need to revert it.